# C++ xstring _Large_string_engaged() const exception

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linked-list, sfml, doubly-linked-list

Hope everyone is doing ok.
So I am making a simulation of a shop where a customer enters a shop, does shopping, cashes out and then de-spawns. A customer is spawned after a random amount of time. I am using Linked List to store these customers. This program uses SFML for graphics.
So I wanted to test my code to have a look at my progress and in order to speed things up, I reduced the amount of time taken for a customer to spawn, the customers started spawning at a fast rate.
So somewhere along the program when there are so many customers at a time, my program stops and gives me the following exception from the xstring header file:

```
bool _Large_string_engaged() const {
    return _BUF_SIZE <= _Myres;
}
```

This exception only appears when a lot of customers have spawned inside the shop at a time. However I think this exception isn't due to spawning a lot of them but in fact when it comes to deleting them or something. Here is the part of the code after which I started facing this error:

```
void CashOutCustomer() {
        SPointer = head;
        while (SPointer) {
            SPointer->customer.customer.setTexture(SPointer->customer._customer);
            SPointer->customer.CashOut(&cashier1, &cashier2, &cashier3);
            if (SPointer->customer.DeleteTime) {
                this->DeleteCustomer(SPointer); Count--; cout << "Count: " << Count << endl;
            }
            SPointer = SPointer->next;
        }
    }

    void DeleteCustomer(ShopStruct *S) {            //Fix deleting
        ShopStruct *TempNext, *TempPrev, *TempDelete;
        if (head == S) {
            TempNext = S->next; head = TempNext;
            TempDelete = S; S = head; 
            head->previous = nullptr; TempDelete->customer.~Customer();
        }
        else if(S->next == nullptr) {
            TempDelete = S; S = S->previous; S->next = nullptr; TempDelete->customer.~Customer();
        }
        else {
            TempNext = S->next; TempPrev = S->previous; TempDelete = S;
            TempNext->previous = TempPrev; TempPrev->next = TempNext;
            S = TempPrev; TempDelete->customer.~Customer();
        }
    }
```

Some points to note:

These functions keep running in a while loop. This while loop is for SFML to keep the graphics window running.

I ONLY face this exception when I speed up the spawning of the customers.

My guess is that the program is too fast due to the SFML while loop because of which the memory gets filled up quickly or something. However I am not sure so I would like to know why and when this exception appears. What does this exception represent?

I appreciate all the help. Thank you!

EDIT:
It seems that this exception appears whenever I speed up the spawning of the customers. It has nothing to do with the deletion of customers. So I am going to post the whole class of the shop (which is a linked list):

```
struct ShopStruct {
Customer customer;
ShopStruct *next, *previous;
};

class Shop {
private:
    ShopStruct *head, *SPointer;
    int ShopLimit; float SpawnTime;
    Clock clock;

public:
    int Count, g = 0;
    Aisle aisle1, aisle2, aisle3;
    Cashier cashier1, cashier2, cashier3;

    Shop() : aisle1("A", "B", 1, 2), aisle2("C", "D", 3, 4), aisle3("E", "F", 5, 6) {
        head = nullptr; Count = 0;  ShopLimit = 20; SpawnTime = 0;
        srand(time(0));
    }

    void CreateCustomer() {
        if (!head) {
            head = new ShopStruct;
            head->previous = head->next = nullptr; Count++;
        }
        else {
            Customer c;
            ShopStruct* NShop = new ShopStruct; NShop->next = nullptr; NShop->customer = c;
            SPointer = head;
            while (SPointer->next)
                SPointer = SPointer->next;
            NShop->previous = SPointer; SPointer->next = NShop;
            Count++;
        }
    }

    void SpawnCustomer(bool isOpen) {
        float y;
        y = clock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds();
        if (g == 0 || !isOpen) {
            SpawnTime = rand() % 2; //change to 16 and 7
            clock.restart(); g = 1;
        }
        else if (Count <= 30 && isOpen && y >= SpawnTime) {
            this->CreateCustomer(); g = 0; cout << "Count: " << Count << endl;
        }
    }

    void CustomerShop() {
        SPointer = head;
        while (SPointer) {
            SPointer->customer.customer.setTexture(SPointer->customer._customer);
            SPointer->customer.WalkShop(&aisle1, &aisle2, &aisle3, &cashier1, &cashier2, &cashier3);
            SPointer = SPointer->next;
        }
    }

    void drawCustomer(RenderWindow *M) {
        Sprite temp;
        SPointer = head;
        while (SPointer) {
            M->draw(SPointer->customer.customer);
            SPointer = SPointer->next;
        }
    }

    void Restock(RenderWindow *M) {
        aisle1.RestockStack(1285, 1530, 230, "A", "B", 1, 2, M);
        aisle2.RestockStack(1285, 1530, 495, "C", "D", 3, 4, M);
        aisle3.RestockStack(1285, 1530, 785, "E", "F", 5, 6, M);
    }

    void CashOutCustomer() {
        SPointer = head;
        while (SPointer) {
            SPointer->customer.customer.setTexture(SPointer->customer._customer);
            SPointer->customer.CashOut(&cashier1, &cashier2, &cashier3);
            if (SPointer->customer.DeleteTime) {
                this->DeleteCustomer(SPointer); Count--; cout << "Count: " << Count << endl;
            }
            SPointer = SPointer->next;
        }
    }

    void DeleteCustomer(ShopStruct *S) {            //Fix deleting
        ShopStruct *TempNext, *TempPrev, *TempDelete;
        if (head == S) {
            TempNext = S->next; head = TempNext;
            TempDelete = S; S = head; 
            head->previous = nullptr; TempDelete->customer.~Customer();
        }
        else if(S->next == nullptr) {
            TempDelete = S; S = S->previous; S->next = nullptr; TempDelete->customer.~Customer();
        }
        else {
            TempNext = S->next; TempPrev = S->previous; TempDelete = S;
            TempNext->previous = TempPrev; TempPrev->next = TempNext;
            S = TempPrev; TempDelete->customer.~Customer();
        }
    }
 };
```

Comment: Getting an error from `string` probably means that you tried to access a deleted string by mistake.

Comment: `TempDelete->customer.~Customer();` is almost certainly wrong

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. It looks like you're simply trying to access a `std::string` that has been destroyed, in which case this has nothing to do with customers or SFML. Please try and [edit] your post to contain a short and self-contained piece of code that reproduces the error

Comment: Is there any reason for doing these gymnastics with raw pointers and explicit linked lists? You should be using normal containers like `std::vector<Customer>` and focusing on solving just one problem at a time

Comment: @alterigel I am using linked lists as a project requirement for my university.

Comment: @Zereff I'm sorry to hear that. Your university is teaching terrible habits

Comment: @alterigel I will look into the strings section of my program then.

Comment: Owww why are you manually invoking destructors?

Comment: @alterigel Teaching how to implement a basic data structure is hardly unusual or "terrible". Would you really rather students never learnt such fundamental skills?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I am calling the destructors to make sure that the customer is deleted once he is done leaving the shop.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings knowing how data structures work is of course vitally important. I'm simply commenting on combining implementation details of low-level data structures with high-level business logic in the same code, which leads to confusion and unreadable code.

Comment: @alterigel My bad. You are totally right about the confusion part.

Comment: @alterigel That much is certainly true

Comment: ***I am calling the destructors to make sure that the customer is deleted once he is done leaving the shop.*** This is the wrong approach. There are rare occasions to call the destructor (using placement new in your code) but this is not one of them. This is likely the source of your bug because the destructor will be called a second time when the object is deleted.